# How to execute a code when a push notification is received on Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, push-notification, safari, notifications

I would like to execute a code on my website that tells my users they received a push notification on safari. Is there a way to do implement this?

I already implemented this on chrome and firefox using the Push Event and a service worker. I tried using the same implementation on safari but it does not trigger the event.

I checked the [specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/onpush) for the onPush event and it says that Safari is supported but when adding the event it does not trigger on safari.